# How to reuse JSON arguments within PostgreSQL stored procedure

Tags: json, postgresql, stored-procedures

I am using a stored procedure to INSERT into and UPDATE a number of tables. Some of the data is derived from a JSON parameter.

Although I have successfully used `json_to_recordset()` to extract named data from the JSON parameter, I cannot figure how to use it in an UPDATE statement. Also, I need to use some items of data from the JSON parameter a number of times.

Q: Is there a way to use `json_to_recordset()` to extract named data to a temporary table to allow me to reuse the data items throughout my stored procedure? Maybe I should SELECT INTO variables within the stored procedure?

Q: Failing that can anyone please provide a simple example of how to update a table using data returned from `json_to_recordset()`. I must also include data not from the JSON parameter such as `now()::timestamp(0)`.

This is how I have used `json_to_recordset()` so far:

```
INSERT INTO myRealTable (
    rec_timestamp,
    rec_data1,
    rec_data2
    )
    SELECT
        now()::timestamp(0),
        x.data1,
        x.data2
    FROM json_to_recordset(json_parameter) x
    (
        json_data1 int,
        json_data2 boolean
    );
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please take a few minuets [ask]. In particular the table definition (ddl) (at least one Insert and Update if not the same table), the stored procedure, the Json parameter and the expected results. All as text - **no images**.

Comment: Clearly this question is only going to attract criticism and not going to elicit any usable help. Please go ahead and delete it.